# Тире перед или после "это"

Tags: пунктуация

В этих примерах тире ставится после слова *это*:

> Боже мой, я секретарь земской управы, той управы, где председательствует Протопопов, я секретарь, и самое большее, на что я могу надеяться, это — быть членом земской управы! (Чехов)
>
> -- По-моему, самое лучшее,  что вы можете теперь сделать, это — совсем
> оставить медицинский  факультет. (Чехов)

В этих — после:

> Мои совесть и ум говорят мне, что самое лучшее, что я могу теперь сделать, — это прочесть мальчикам прощальную лекцию... (Чехов)

Откуда этот разнобой и как предпочтительнее писать?

Comment: Кстати, первый ваш пример не соотвествует тексту произведения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тире обычно ставится перед «это». Тем не менее, так как тире — популярный знак авторской пунктуации для подчёркивания интонации и противопоставлений, оно часто появляется там, где оно не обязательно (а в старых произведениях — и там, где по современным нормам его вряд ли бы поставили).

Answer (score 5):

При подлежащем, выраженном словом это, между главными членами предложения тире ставится в зависимости от логического выделения подлежащего и наличия паузы после него; ср.: Это — начало всех начал.  Это неплохое начало; Это — одиночество (Ч.). — Это дом Зверкова (Г.).

То же в вашем примере.

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь, Д. Э. [Тире между членами предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91), 
Полный академический справочник. [Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)